# Exported PDF is not accurate (even though PrintingStyleEnvironment -> "Working")

Tags: plotting, graphics, export, pdf-format, polygons

I considered a simple example using the PolygonMaker resource function from:
https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/resourcesystem/published/FunctionRepository/resources/PolygonMarker/

```mathematica
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, PrintingStyleEnvironment -> "Working"];
fm[name_String, size_ : 8] := ResourceFunction["PolygonMarker"][name, Offset[size], EdgeForm[]];
SeedRandom[25];
g = ListPlot[Table[Accumulate@RandomReal[1, 10] + i, {i, 6}], PlotMarkers -> fm /@ {"Triangle", "Y", "Diamond", "ThreePointedStar", "FivePointedStarSlim", "TripleCross"}, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> ColorData[52, "ColorList"], PlotLegends -> PointLegend[Automatic, LegendMarkerSize -> {50, 37}, LegendLayout -> (Column[Row /@ #, Spacings -> -1] &)], ImageSize -> 450]
```

This code result in the following picture, which matches what found on the website.

[image]

However, exporting the graph to PDF with

```mathematica
Export["test.pdf", g]
```

Produces a PDF looking like this:

[image]

I have noticed other issues, for instance decreasing the size of the marker results in artifacts in the PDF where the markers gets truncated at the borders.

Is this a known issue or am I missing some settings to produce fully conforming PDFs?